# Two different variables with same String value are referred to same memory address

Tags: java, string, jvm

I know that Strings are immutable. But I have a doubt in below code:

```
class StringTest {
   String s1 = "Joe";
   String s2 = "Joe";
   System.out.println(s1 == s2);
}
```

**==** checks whether both are referred to same memory address or not (if I am not wrong). If so, even the two strings are assigned to two different variables, why the output says both are referred to same memory address.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses an [intern pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) for performance, and so those two variables refer to the same `String`. You can use `new` to get a new one, like

```
class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Joe";
        String s2 = new String("Joe");
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }
}
```